# Foreign key Constraint Conflict

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

Hey i am using sql server to design the database of a general store management along with java fx framework. I have used queries for entering the record of a specific item, as i have to enter the supplier data item data along with inventory purposes so i have to input data on various relations on one time. For that purpose i have used this query:`

```
DECLARE @productId int
EXEC @productId=spGetProductId @Name='Daal'

DECLARE @supplierId int
EXEC @supplierId=spGetSupplierId @Name='Samar'

INSERT INTO Purchase(Supplier_Id, Product_id, Quantity)
VALUES(@supplierId, @productId, 20)
`
```

and after executing this code it gives me following error:

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   "FK_Purchase_Supplier". The conflict occurred in database
>   "GeneralStoreManagement", table "dbo.Supplier", column 'Supplier_Id'.

Note: If i enter direct foreign keys without declaring the variables it doesn't gives me any error and proceeds to insert statement.

Comment: What about the error is it you don't understand? I would suggest that the values you *think* your variables have the values they have are not the same. Also, I suggest against the syntax `EXEC {Variable} = {Stored Procedure} [{Input Paramteters}]`. You should really be using `OUTPUT` parameters.

Comment: spGetSupplierId doesn't give you correct supplier_id or it return null. If you put the spGetSupplierId  procedure  detail we can help you better.

Comment: Functions seems to be more appropriate than procedures to return data, then using it inline. `SELECT @supplierId = dbo.getSupplierId('Samar')`. Although output parameters may be a solution, as @Larnu said